# how to read the Broadcast Wave Format info in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been given some wav files in BWF format and I need to extract the date stamp from them using Matlab.  I've done some work reading/writing standard WAV headers, but I'm completely lost when it comes to the BWF format.  I've read through the EBU descriptions and various webpages regarding the format - even more confused then before.  I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of some code that I could look at to actually see how to read the data.  It doesn't have to be Matlab - I just need an example to help me understand.  Any help would be appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can get some clues by having a look to the source code of [BWFMetaEdit](http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/).

There's a Riff_Chunks_WAVE_bext.cpp file to begin with.